# Tmux Status Line detect Vim

Tags: vim, terminal, tmux, iterm2

How can I get Tmux to detect Vim in current session?

I want to make status-right dissapear when I have Vim open in foreground and reappear otherwise.  How do I do this?  I'm thinking of using set-hook -g?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the text in status-right conditional on pane_current_command, for example something like:

```
set -gF @old-status-right '#{status-right}'
set -g status-right '#{?#{==:#{pane_current_command},vim},,#{E:@old-status-right}}'
```

Look at https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Formats for syntax.